# Get data back after validating a Coupon with Ruby on Rails using AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

On my Rails app I have a requirement to validate coupons and provide feedback to the user about the kind of discount they will receive.

I have been able to successfully check if the coupon is valid or invalid using AJAX. Now I am trying to show data about the Coupon but have been unsuccessful so far in my attempts.

I have a Model called `Coupon` with the fields of `code` and `discount`.

Here is my controller code:

```
class CouponsController < ApplicationController

  def show
  end

  def check_coupon_code

    if Coupon.exists?(:code => params[:coupon])
      valid = true
      @coupon = Coupon.find_by(:code => params[:coupon])
      puts "Code Valid"
    else
      valid = false
      puts "Code Invalid"
    end
    respond_to do |format|
      if valid
        format.json { render :json => @coupon }
      else
        format.json { }
      end
      return
    end

  end

end
```

Javascript on the form:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#subscription_stripe_coupon').change(function(){
      coupon_code = $('#subscription_stripe_coupon').val();
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/coupons/check_coupon_code",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: { coupon : coupon_code},
        success: function(data){
          if (response) {
            console.log("Valid Code!");
          } else {
            console.log("Invalid Code!");
          }
        }
      });
    });
  });
</script>
```

My route:

```
post 'coupons/check_coupon_code' => 'coupons#check_coupon_code'
```

Here's the logs on an invalid coupon:

```
Started POST "/coupons/check_coupon_code" for 50.17.182.190 at 2015-09-23 03:02:35 +0000
Processing by CouponsController#check_coupon_code as JSON
  Parameters: {"coupon"=>"asdf"}
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = 1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
  Coupon Exists (0.1ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "coupons"  WHERE "coupons"."code" = 'asdf' LIMIT 1
Code Invalid
  Rendered coupons/check_coupon_code.html.erb within layouts/application (0.3ms)
  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (1.0ms)
  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.4ms)
Completed 200 OK in 52ms (Views: 48.1ms | ActiveRecord: 0.6ms)
```

Here's the logs on a valid coupon:

```
Started POST "/coupons/check_coupon_code" for 50.17.182.190 at 2015-09-23 03:19:21 +0000
Processing by CouponsController#check_coupon_code as JSON
  Parameters: {"coupon"=>"STARTUPBROS2015"}
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = 1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (1.6ms)  UPDATE "users" SET "last_seen_at" = $1, "updated_at" = $2 WHERE "users"."id" = 1  [["last_seen_at", "2015-09-23 03:19:21.651990"], ["updated_at", "2015-09-23 03:19:21.653000"]]
   (0.9ms)  COMMIT
  Coupon Exists (0.2ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "coupons"  WHERE "coupons"."code" = 'STARTUPBROS2015' LIMIT 1
  Coupon Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "coupons".* FROM "coupons"  WHERE "coupons"."code" = 'STARTUPBROS2015' LIMIT 1
Code Valid
  Rendered coupons/check_coupon_code.html.erb within layouts/application (0.3ms)
  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (0.9ms)
  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.4ms)
Completed 200 OK in 58ms (Views: 47.9ms | ActiveRecord: 3.3ms)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change `response` into `data` in you condition. Then, Please update the ajax into below:

```
<script>
  $('#subscription_stripe_coupon').change(function () {
      coupon_code = $('#subscription_stripe_coupon').val();
      $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "/coupons/check_coupon_code",
          dataType: 'json',
          data: {coupon: coupon_code}
      }).done(function (data) {
          console.log(data);
          if (data) {
              console.log("Valid Code!");
          } else {
              console.log("Invalid Code!");
          }
      }).fail(function () {
          console.log("error");
      }).always(function () {
          console.log("complete");
      });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. Unfortunately nothing came through on console for that either :(

Comment: Hey, thanks for the update.. I got error and complete both in my console.. but no data

Comment: What for `return` in  `check_coupon_code`? Try to remove it first.

Comment: Booyah, that did it.. Thank you mate! Do you want to add that to the answer for completeness?

Comment: really? It's ajax request. Can you give me log server?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90387/discussion-between-muhamad-akbar-bin-widayat-and-bnussey).